# Working dynamically with nested lists python

Tags: python, list, nested

I'm trying to create a program for class that takes user input of student names then asks for three additional inputs (per student) for specific grades.

```
Patrick - Discussion Grade (50), Quiz Grade (50), Assignment Grade (50).
Michael - Discussion Grade (60), Quiz Grade (60), Assignment Grade (60).
```

I'm assuming the best way to do this would to create a nested list, correct? I was thinking it would look something like:

```
[patrick[discussion=50,quiz=50,assignment=50]michael[discussion=60,quiz=60,assignment=60]]
```

Using other posts on StackOverflow as well as 8 hours of trying to figure this out, I've come up with:

```
#A loop to create specific amount of lists depending on input supplied above
    listObject={}
    for i in range(0,studentNumber):
        listObject["G: "+str(i+1)]=[]
        print(listObject)
    
    discussionGradeStorage=[]
    quizGradeStorage=[]
    assignmentGradeStorage=[]
    
    gradeCount=0
    while gradeCount < 3:
        gradeCount+=1
        for i in range(0,len(studentNameList)):
            while True:
                try:
                    discussionGrades=int(input("Please round and enter discussion grade number "+str(gradeCount)+" for "+studentNameList[i].title()+" "))
                    quizGrades=int(input("Please round and enter quiz grade number "+str(gradeCount)+" for "+studentNameList[i].title()+" "))
                    assignmentGrades=int(input("Please round and enter assignment number "+str(gradeCount)+" for "+studentNameList[i].title()+" "))
                    discussionGradeStorage.append(discussionGrades)
                    quizGradeStorage.append(quizGrades)
                    assignmentGradeStorage.append(assignmentGrades)
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("This is wrong. Try again.")
                    continue
    print(discussionGradeStorage)
    print(quizGradeStorage)
    print(assignmentGradeStorage)
```

I know this is annoying to read through, but I'm trying to do this for a class I'm taking. I'm assuming this would require some variation of for loop perhaps within the last while True assessment, but I'm not sure how to assign the variables dynamically into a list so that I can call them dynamically and perform functions like finding the average for each student. Here are my assignment instructions:

I've attempted to create singular lists which I thought about trying to combine, but I still wouldn't be sure on how to index them. I've also found a snippet of code to help create a nested list, but I don't know how to dynamically place data into it.

Comment: You're looking for a dict of dicts: `{"patrick": {"phone": 10}, "spongebob": {"burger": 42}}`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something along these lines, using a [`dict` (a dictionary, not a list)](https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) that maps student names to nested `dict`s that map subjects to grades.

I refactored the integer prompting to a separate function, since it's used in multiple places.

For the heck of it, the program will also print out the average of each student's grades at the end.

You can also print out `student_grades` at the end to see what the data structure looks like; it'll be something like

```
{'aa': {'assignment': 67, 'discussion': 12, 'quiz': 45},
 'bb': {'assignment': 35, 'discussion': 78, 'quiz': 14},
 'cc': {'assignment': 63, 'discussion': 77, 'quiz': 23}}
```

```
from statistics import mean


def prompt_integer(prompt, min_value=None, max_value=None):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("This is not an integer. Try again.")
            continue

        if min_value is not None and value < min_value:
            print("This is too small. Try again.")
            continue

        if max_value is not None and value > max_value:
            print("This is too large. Try again.")
            continue

        return value


def student_info(subjects):
    student_count = prompt_integer(
        "Please enter how many students you have to grade for. "
        "Amount must be between 3 and 30. ",
        min_value=3,
        max_value=30,
    )
    student_names = [
        input(f"Please enter the name of student number {i + 1}: ")
        for i in range(student_count)
    ]
    student_grades = {}
    for student_name in student_names:
        student_grades[student_name] = {}
        for subject in subjects:
            student_grades[student_name][subject] = prompt_integer(
                f"Please enter {subject} grade number for {student_name}: ",
                min_value=0,
                max_value=100,
            )

    for student_name, grades in student_grades.items():
        for subject, grade in grades.items():
            print(f"{student_name} got a {grade} on {subject}.")
        print(f"{student_name} got an average of {mean(grades.values())}.")


student_info(["discussion", "quiz", "assignment"])
```

Comment: This was perfect! I /think/ I understand all of it, but I'm not 100% about the final for loop. Is the "subject, grade" just defining the value in the place of that part of the dict?

Comment: [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) yields pairs of `key, value`, so it's not "defining the value", it's reading them and giving them that local name.